# Pyinstaller - Running executable from Popen on MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have created an executable using Pyinstaller 4.8 on MAC OSX. The Python script (which was converted to executable) is executing another executable (named `run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch` using `subprocess.Popen`.

The command to execute `run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch` (the executable not a shell script) through `Popen` (at line 189 in the screenshot below) is below:

```
batch_command = "run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch '" + loc_pb + "'" + additional_json_cmds + "'" + path_to_image_folder + "' '" + loc_json_file + "'"
batch_command = [batch_command]
```

[image]

It works as expected if I run it from the terminal.

The problem is when I run it by double-clicking it. I face the below error:

[image]

I understand that the problem is `run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch` being interpreted as a shell script by OSX and it looks for a shell script.

Question: How to solve this?

Comment: Does it work when you use an absolute path?

Comment: Nope. It still takes it as a shell script

Comment: But when the file is not found it is not being taken as anything?

Comment: Yes! It just reports an error saying that file is not found.

Comment: I think I would check the output of `ls -l run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch`

Comment: `ls` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 peter staff 15378784 Dec 30 12:30 run_tf_detector_batch/run_tf_detector_batch`